# htaccess rewrite only working with numbers

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to rewrite different url's in this way:

> myPage.de/static/about => myPage.de/index.php?st=about

The same for some other catagories like static.

I created this htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^static/(\d+)*$ ./index.php?st=$1
RewriteRule ^content/(\d+)*$ ./index.php?cl=$1
```

This seems to work whenever i try something like: myPage.de/static/123 (123 is then given as parmeter) when i do something like myPage.de/static/test I always receive an object not found error in my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(\d+)` means one or more digits. Change it to `(.*)` if you want it to match everything. The `*` before `$` can also be removed.

```
RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ /index.php?st=$1
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)$ /index.php?cl=$1
```

Comment: working perfectly well! Thansk a lot! Will mark this as correct asap